# Adding features to ServiceStack auth provider

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am evaluating ServiceStack using OrmLite. The built in Auth service, along with Session and Cache are so much better than ASP.NET membership provider.

However, out of the box the Auth Service does not provide some of the features required for apps we want to build like:

- Change password
- Locking of account after 3 unsuccessful logon attempts
- Disabling user accounts
- Password reminder question and answer
- Audit log of log on attempts

Do I need to build custom auth provider or is there something out there which already does provides this functionality?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting to implement a password reset and can see two ways of achieving it (I've not tested - or even tried - either yet):

1.Create a class that inherits from Registration and handles PUT.  It should then be possible to call the UpdateUserAuth method of the registration class which would change the password.  The problem - for me - here is that the put validation requires username and password to be specified, not just one (We only use email as an identifier).  This could be worked around by turning the validation feature off.

2.Create a password reset service that does what UpdateUserAuth does.

```
var session = this.GetSession();
var existingUser = UserAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session, null);
if (existingUser == null)
{
    throw HttpError.NotFound("User does not exist");
}

var newUserAuth = ToUserAuth(request);
UserAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(newUserAuth, existingUser, request.Password);
```

Obviously need to add some appropriate validation in.

**UPDATED**

I've put my change password reminder/reset service up as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/miketrebilcock/5195817) (My first gist!)

Comment: I think for Account Lockout and Account Disabling I would extend the Credentials Auth Provider.  Probably using the cache provider to store the invalid login attempts and possible the lockout/disabling if they were both time-based.

Comment: If you wrote it as a feature, then submitted a Pull request back to service stack we could all use it!

Comment: Yes, I am studying the code to determine the minimum possible change required to accomplish this. At the moment, it looks like I will have to create a new service. I am not sure about whether to worry about open auth providers, as they will not be able to provide the same level of functionality as credentials provider.

Answer (score 1):

here's what I did, works well. - I realise the "new" is a code-smell, just inject it :)

```
        private int LoginAttempts = 0;

    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        var authRepo = authService.TryResolve<IUserAuthRepository>();

        if (authRepo == null)
        {
            Log.WarnFormat("Tried to authenticate without a registered IUserAuthRepository");
            return false;
        }


        var session = authService.GetSession();

        UserAuth userAuth = null;

        if (authRepo.TryAuthenticate(userName, password, out userAuth))
        {
            session.PopulateWith(userAuth);

            session.IsAuthenticated = true;

            session.UserAuthId = userAuth.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            session.ProviderOAuthAccess = authRepo.GetUserOAuthProviders(session.UserAuthId)
                .ConvertAll(x => (IOAuthTokens)x);


            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            LoginAttempts++;

            if (LoginAttempts >= 3)
            {
                ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service s = new Service();

                s.Db.ExecuteSql("update [User] set AccountLocked = 'true' where Email='" + userName + "'");
            }

            authService.RemoveSession();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and I hope the mod_from_hell manages to leave this alone!!!

Comment: I'm afraid there are serious mistakes that you're doing and that put your app into jeopardy:

  - The LoginAttempts variable is global for your whole app. What happens if more users put in the wrong passwords at the same time? Do you reset the counter after successful attempt?

  - You're using sql with unescaped data, this is a major vulnerability since it can be used for SQL injection